# Devsie with OpenID throwing error uninitialized constant Devise::Schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, openid

I have created a new rails app (3.2.8) using Devise. All is setup properly, the app starts, I can register as well as login.

I then added `devise_openid_authenticatable` which I understand is the gem to use for OpenID integration in devise. I followed the instructions on https://github.com/nbudin/devise_openid_authenticatable

But when I want to do rake db:migrate I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Devise::Schema
```

When running `rails s` I get

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/devise_openid_authenticatable-1.0.0/lib/devise_openid_authenticatable/schema.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise::Schema (NameError)
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/devise_openid_authenticatable-1.0.0/lib/devise_openid_authenticatable.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
```

My Gemfile looks as follows (last two lines):

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_openid_authenticatable'
```

And the User model as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :timeoutable, :openid_authenticatable
    attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

How to resolve the error?

Comment: I also had the same issue, did you find another gem for this that supports devise 2.0+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `devise_openid_authenticatable` gem doesn't look as though it has been maintained and updated to work with any current version of Devise.

From the gems gemspec:

```
gem.add_dependency "devise", "~> 1.3"
```

Which means that it will only work with 1.x versions of Devise. I think instead you may have better luck using something newer that is more well maintained. Have a look through this page on the Devise Wiki and you may find what you are looking for.
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview